# Restart Flutter Flow Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I have a Flutter app that I built to allow product input into our product library. I am using the library `flow_builder`. This library allows me to use a single model to declare the data being stored in a sequence of screens. It works perfectly with regards to this purpose: The flow of the input works perfectly, until I attempt to 'reset' the app to the beginning.

When I get to the end of the flow, I want to be able to start over and add another entry. When I attempt to do this, things break. The behavior I'm seeing is that it *will* return to the main screen, the values will be erased, but it will not restart the flow.

My flow is defined as:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlowBuilder<FormDetails>(
      state: FormDetails(),
      onGeneratePages: (product, pages) {
        return [
          const MaterialPage(child: ProductDetailsForm()),
          if (product.name != null)
            const MaterialPage(child: ProductLocation()),
          if (product.location != null)
            const MaterialPage(child: ProductBudgetScreen()),
          if (product.budgetAmount != null)
            const MaterialPage(child: EndScreenModal())
        ];
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm attempting to reset by going to the first page:

```
         TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const ProductDetailsForm())),
            child: const Text('Start Over'),
          )
```

Part of me suspects that what I want is not possible, but I figured I would ask here before giving up and going a different route.